# Como enviar um formulário automaticamente quando os inputs estiverem preenchidos?

Tags: javascript

Tenho dois `input` num formulário, que na verdade é um placar de um jogo. Quero que envie esse placar com `focusout()` quando o usuário preencher os dois campos do `form`.

Meu formulário está assim:

```html
<form method="post" id="form1" action="teste2.php">
  <label>Time1</label>
  <input type="text" name="gols1" id="gols1">
  <label>Time2</label>
  <input type="text" name="gols2" id="gols2">
</form>
```

É um formulário simples com dois inputs e quero enviá-lo sem ter que colocar botão de enviar, quero que envie quando perder o foco.

Comment: Não faça isso, pense em seus usuários. S e o cara digitar algo errado, ou so clicar sem querer você já vai submeter os dados errados? E como vai validar se terminou de preencher? Se for quando o campo perder o foco o cara pode começar a digitar e clicar fora do form atoa e enviar sem querer... não recomendaria isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode aguardar pelo evento `blur` nos inputs e se ambos estiverem com um valor definido, o formulário será submetido.

```js
(function() {

  var $gols1 = document.getElementById('gols1'),
      $gols2 = document.getElementById('gols2');

  function handleSubmit(){
    if ($gols1.value && $gols2.value)
      alert('Formulário enviado.');
  }

  $gols1.addEventListener('blur', handleSubmit);
  $gols2.addEventListener('blur', handleSubmit);
})();
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form1" action="teste2.php">
  <label for='gols1'>Time1</label>
  <input type="text" name="gols1" id="gols1">
  <label for='gols2'>Time2</label>
  <input type="text" name="gols2" id="gols2">
</form>
```

No exemplo eu coloquei um `alert()` somente para mostrar o momento em que o formulário foi enviado. No seu caso, você enviaria o formulário substituindo o `alert()` por `document.getElementById('form1').submit();`.

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

olha, você não precisa de JavaScript para realizar isto, pode usar a tag `required`.

```html
<form method="post" id="form1" action="teste2.php">
  <div>
    <label for="gols1">Time1</label>
    <input type="text" name="gols1" id="gols1" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="gols2">Time2</label>
    <input type="text" name="gols2" id="gols2" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder amigo! Mas eu nao quero que tenha um botao submit no form, apenas os dois inputs, e quando ele preencher os dois e sair do input , envia o form

Comment: @user41251, vejo que alguem aqui andou faltando as aulas de UX.