# Enviar form com Input hidden automaticamente após ser preenchido

Tags: php

Preciso enviar esse form sem precisar de nenhuma ação, apenas quando os input hidden forem preenchidos. Sem botão, sem ação, só enviar...

Sei que existem perguntas como: "[Como enviar um formulário automaticamente quando os inputs estiverem preenchidos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114809/como-enviar-um-formul%C3%A1rio-automaticamente-quando-os-inputs-estiverem-preenchidos)" 
que me atendem 70% pois, ali ele adiciona manualmente os valores e aciona então  a função.
Mas quando tenho o preenchimento automático dos inputs hidden ele não reconhece e não faz o envio. 
Segue o codigo..

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
                    <div class="form-row" >                                                              
                             <input name="nome" type="hidden" value="$var">                                                        
                    </div>                                              
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular</button>
                </form>
```

Quero que esse código envie automaticamente no processamento da pagina, sem interferência visual ou mecânica. teria como?

as variáveis recebem os valores no processamento da pagina.

Comment: Não consegui entender direito o que você deseja fazer. Poderia esclarecer um pouco mais a sua pergunta?

Comment: Você tentou colocar o valor no input? Exemplo: `<input name="nome" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $var" ?>`

Comment: Ola, sim ele está com valor tudo certinho só preciso que ele envie sem eu fazer nenhuma ação, vou editar algumas coisas no topico

Answer (score 1):

A única forma que imagino nessa situação é colocando um jQuery, sendo que você já preenche os campos por php.

```
$(window).load( function(){ $('.btn').trigger('click'); });
```

Oh senão um próprio `$('form').submit()` no final da página.