# Sistema para ler código de barras pelo celular em PHP, está funcionando. mas queria saber Como usar o $_GET Somente quando o usuário fizer a leitura

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Ele mostra esse erro porque fez o get antes mesmo do usuário clicar em "Cód de barra", onde é redirecionado para o app para realizar a leitura do cód de barras. após ele ler, o erro desaparece e é preenchido o código de barras normalmente.
Só tirar este erro colocando o $_GET somente após o usuário ler o cód de barras

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está confundindo conceitos, para gerar esta tela do lado servidor, executará o código PHP, por  isso ao enviar ao navegador já terá rodado o $_GET

Comment: sim, como eu faço para rodar o GET somente após o usuário ler o código? quero deixar em branco por padrão

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você deve usar **[isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)**, onde verifica se a variável foi iniciada.

Seu código ficaria algo como:

```
<?=isset($_GET['codigo']) ? $_GET['codigo'] : '';?>
```

Sendo false, não retorna um Warning.

Comment: Funcionou amigo! você é fera! tem como forçar um enter pelo php assim que for preenchido?

Comment: Sim, é possível. Um exemplo aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114809/como-enviar-um-formul%C3%A1rio-automaticamente-quando-os-inputs-estiverem-preenchidos

Comment: Opa, aqui não funcionou pois o meu é somente um input. não tem um form e nem submit :(

Comment: Qual a função do "enter"? Enviar o que? Para onde? Qualquer coisa abra uma nova pergunta.